# Where am I going with this?

Tags: wh-questions

What does "**Where am I going with this?** " mean in the below paragraph?
When can we use it in English?

> Or how about the song ‘twinkle, twinkle little star’, you know,
>   ‘twinkle, twinkle, little star, how I wonder what you are’. Well,
>   we’ve all heard this song. Where am I going with this? Well, both the
>   song and the story are examples of memes. And that’s what we would
>   talk about, the theory of memes.

Comment: it means that the speaker, has been talking about somthing that seems unrelated to the discussion's topic. The speaker asks that  (rhetorical) question, just before they explain how what they were saying actually is related to the topic of discussion. The audience is expected to pretend they they asked the question, rather than the speaker, and what follows is his answer. "Where am I going with this you might ask?" is another form of the sentence, and is a little clearer on who is doing the asking and who is doing the answering. its particular to speech, and rarely written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Where am I going with this" is a fairly common *rhetorical question* used mainly informally.

It means "where is this line of thought leading", or "what is the point I am making".

The speaker/writer asks it of themselves, often after a lengthy introduction, and usually leads into them making their final point. It is intentionally humorous and suggests that the audience may be at this point wondering if they are just rambling or actually have a point to make.